# Let $F : X → X$ be continuous. Prove that the set $\{x ∈ X : F(x) = x\}$ of fixed points of F is closed in X

Tags: general-topology

Here X is a Hausdorff Space.

I know that singleton sets, {x}, are closed in a Hausdorff space. Although Im not sure if thats how to use the Hausdorff property.

Should I investigate $h=F(x)-x$?

Can anyone give a hint

Comment: Since $X$ is an "abstract" space, addition/soustraction may not be well-defined. You can try to prove that the complement of this set is open.

Comment: Hint: A space $X$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal is closed in $X \times X$.

Comment: Hint: One approach is to show that the graph of a continuous function $X\to Y$ is a closed set of $X\times Y$ when $X,Y$ are Hausdorff.

Comment: This follows from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1650441/4280 taking $g(x)= x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general you can’t investigate $F(x)-x$, since the operation of subtraction may not make any sense in the space $X$.

HINT: One straightforward approach is to show that the set of non-fixed points of $F$ is open. Suppose that $F(x)\ne x$. $X$ is Hausdorff, so there are open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U$, $F(x)\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. Use these open sets and the continuity of $F$ to show that there is an open nbhd $W$ of $x$ such that $F(y)\ne y$ for each $y\in W$.

If you get completely stuck, there’s a further hint in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Show that you can find $W$ such that $x\in W\subseteq U$ and $F[W]\subseteq V$.

Comment: In what way should I use the continuity of F?

Comment: @Connor: What definitions and characterizations of continuity do you know?

Answer (score 1):

A space $X$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal $\Delta$ is closed in $X \times X$.

Now the set of fixed points is exactly $(F\times Id_X)^{-1}(\Delta)$ which is closed by continuity of $F$ (and thus that of $F\times Id_X$).

Answer (score 0):

I have this idea that I'd love somebody with more knowledge than I will check: define a function

$$\;\phi:X\to X\times X\;,\;\;\text{by}\;\;\;\phi(x):=(x,F(x))\;$$

Since each coordinate function is continous also $\;\phi\;$ is, and if $\;\Delta:=\{(x,x)\in X\times X\}\;$ is the diagonal in the cartesian product, then

$$\phi^{-1}(\Delta\cap\phi(X))=\left\{x\in X\;;\;F(x)=x\;\right\}=:K$$

Since $\;\Delta\cap\phi(X)\;$ is closed  (see comments by Ayman Hourieh and Thomas Andres below the question) and $\;\phi\;$ is continous, then $\;K\;$ is closed.

Comment: Hmm...I think my answer is similar to the one by Nitrogen (but Ididn't see it). I'll leave it until someone can read it and eventually check it, and then, if needed, I'll erase it.